# DTS packages, SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, dts

I'm currently in the process of cleaning up a sql server 2000 instance. I found 10 Local Packages that were created 4-5 years ago. In an effort to clean up old processes, I want to delete these packages. My question is, how can I determine if they are still in use. Does the start and end time on the log file suffice? Thanks!

Comment: After you "think" they're not being used, delete but keep a copy just in case.  :)  It could help put out a fire later on.

Comment: how do you save a copy of the package?

Comment: i figured it out. when into design package view and did a save as there.

Answer (score 1):

When you open **`SQL Analyser--> DTS--> Local packages`**, in right side, there is a column named STATUS. It shows whether package is active, inactive, running etc. You can identify directly from there !

Answer (score 0):

You have checked whether any of the package are still part of a schedule?